# gravity forms wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity

I have website with 5 forms.
first form is for register users and after is filled and send user is logged in.
forms 2-5 are for details about user informations
Admin can approve or not each form.
if some forms are not approved user after login to website is redirected to form which was not approved to fill again which correct informations
if all forms are approved then login in redirecting to specific page
can someone help me write function for that?

```
function check_form_approved () {
if ( is_user_logged_in( 'get_current_user_id' ) ) 
    if ( $form = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id['1'] . $entry['approval_status'] == 'approved' ) ) { 
        wp_redirect( 'http://form 2' );
        exit; 
    }
else 
    if ( $form = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id['1'] . $entry['approval_status'] == 'rejected' ) ) { 
        wp_redirect( 'http://form 3' ); 
        exit; 
    }
```

}

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Edit this information into your question. THe Edit-link is below the tags in light gray.

Comment: Added code in question

Comment: Can pay for help if this will work